# Display Open/Closed based on day and time and location

Tags: php, datetime

I have ran through a few test examples I have found and tried to combined some answer but have been unsuccessful.

This is what I have so far & I will actually need to add another one for a second locations hours.

```
    <?php
     date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
     $date = new DateTime;
     echo date("D m/d/y  h:i:s",time())
    ?>

    <?php
    $times = array(
        'mon' => '7:30 AM - 12:00 PM, 12:30 PM - 4:30 PM',
        'tue' => '7:30 AM - 12:00 PM, 12:30 PM - 6:30 PM',
        'wed' => '7:30 AM - 12:00 PM, 3:30 PM - 4:30 PM',
        'thu' => '7:30 AM - 12:00 PM, 12:30 PM - 6:30 PM',
        'fri' => '7:30 AM - 4:30 PM',
        'sat' => '7:30 AM - 12:00 PM',
        'sun' => 'closed'
    );

    function compileHours($times, $timestamp) {
        $times = $times[strtolower(date('D',$timestamp))];
        if(!strpos($times, '-')) return array();
        $hours = explode(",", $times);
        $hours = array_map('explode', array_pad(array(),count($hours),'-'), $hours);
        $hours = array_map('array_map', array_pad(array(),count($hours),'strtotime'),         $hours, array_pad(array(),count($hours),array_pad(array(),2,$timestamp)));
        end($hours);
        if ($hours[key($hours)][0] > $hours[key($hours)][1]) $hours[key($hours)][1] =         strtotime('+1 day', $hours[key($hours)][1]);
        return $hours;
    }

    function isOpen($now, $times) {
        $open = 0; // time until closing in seconds or 0 if closed
        // merge opening hours of today and the day before
        $hours = array_merge(compileHours($times,         strtotime('yesterday',$now)),compileHours($times, $now)); 

        foreach ($hours as $h) {
            if ($now >= $h[0] and $now < $h[1]) {
                $open = $h[1] - $now;
                return $open;
            } 
        }
        return $open;
    }

    $now = strtotime('12:00am');
    $open = isOpen($now, $times);

    if ($open == 0) {
        echo "Closed";
    } else {
        echo "Open";
    }

    ?>
```

Here is the link to the test page I am mess with http://www.sullivanscrap.com/testtime.php Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is it doing and what do you expect it to do instead?

Comment: It is showing closed no matter what time it is. I have changed 'wed' time multiple time with to test it out and it always states closed but the time does change on the page. I am wanting it to change open/closed based on the time set for each day, compared to the actual time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are setting `$now` to midnight of today's morning, then checking that against your hour ranges. This will always return closed because none of your hour ranges contain that time. Changing this to `$now = time()` seems to yield the expected results.

Comment: You are correct! Thank you so very much! Sorry for my delay a tree fell on my house and I was out.